# Ionic4/Angular Post a tweet to Twitter

Tags: angular, http, ionic-framework, twitter

I am developing an APP where I would like a user to tap a button and send a tweet to his/her timeline.
There are a few known methods of how to do this with Node.JS and Angular, but I am looking for a solution to achieve what I want without a Node Server Running.

Is there a way to embed the Twitter API into your IONIC/Angular APP. and I am not looking for the Ionic Plugin TwitterConnect as that does not have a POST Method.

## EDIT

here is the twitter example, but how would I implement this in Angular?

```
curl -XPOST 
  --url 'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/update.json?status=hello' 
  --header 'authorization: OAuth
  oauth_consumer_key="oauth_customer_key",
  oauth_nonce="generated_oauth_nonce",
  oauth_signature="generated_oauth_signature",
  oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1",
  oauth_timestamp="generated_timestamp",
  oauth_token="oauth_token",
  oauth_version="1.0"'
```

here is the link https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/post-and-engage/api-reference/post-statuses-update 
suggested by @Gonzalo Nicolás
Can anyone assist me with documentation or some coded examples.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So as far as I understand this, you can access the Twitter API with a simple node server. Which originally I thought was daunting but really it is not anything to stress about.

you can start your node program
with creating a project directory

```
mkdir server
cd server
npm init
touch server.js
```

and install the twit api and express js into your node project

```
npm install twit body-parser cors express
```

create your twitter app on the twitter developers page
https://apps.twitter.com/

then copy and paste this code into your server.js file which you need to create in your node application, which you can do simply by creating a file called server.js

```
const express = require('express');
const Twitter = require('twit');

const app = express();
const client = new Twitter({
  consumer_key:         '...',
  consumer_secret:      '...',
  access_token:         '...',
  access_token_secret:  '...',
});


app.use(require('cors')());
app.use(require('body-parser').json());

app.post('/post_tweet', (req, res) => {

  tweet = req.body;

  client
    .post(`statuses/update`, tweet)
    .then(tweeting => {
      console.log(tweeting);

      res.send(tweeting);
    })

   .catch(error => {
    res.send(error);
  });


});

app.listen(3000, () => console.log('Server running'));
```

then in your angular project just copy and paste this code and you are all set

```
api_url = 'http://localhost:3000';

  tweet(tweetdata: string) {
    return this.http.post<any>(`${this.api_url}/post_tweet/`, {status: tweetdata})
        .pipe(map(tweet => {

            alert("tweet posted")

            return tweet;
        }));
}
sendTweet() {  
  this.tweet('This is app code')
            .pipe(first())
            .subscribe(
                data => {
                    console.log('yes')
                },
                error => {
                  'failed'
                });
}
```

Answer (score 6):

sorry for my english, i'm from argentina. your solution is POST statuses/update API,
This solution is from twitter, If you search on that, you will find all the documentation and structure that you have to send 
assuming you use auth

link: https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/post-and-engage/api-reference/post-statuses-update

Comment: @Mitch Can anyone assist me with documentation or some coded examples... 
With respect to that I can provide a guide for a client application to understand all the operation of integration with the twitter and angular api. https://www.sitepoint.com/building-twitter-app-using-angular/ 
In this guide I recommend that you begin to first understand the concepts of auth0 for registering with social media accounts

Comment: Nicolas I am using twitter connect to allow the user to login and sign up

Comment: Nicolas check out my answer to this question if you need help

Answer (score 3):

you can try native twitter widget script for tweet in timeline using following code : (I didn't try it in angular/ionic, but working in my html.)

```
// initialization : 

window.twttr = (function (d, s, id) {
    var t, js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
    js = d.createElement(s);
    js.id = id;
    js.src = "https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    return window.twttr || (t = {
        _e: [],
        ready: function (f) {
            t._e.push(f)
        }
    });
}(document, "script", "twitter-wjs"));

// on button click, this will fire  (button will automatically generated by widget.)

twttr.ready(function (twttr) {
    twttr.widgets.createShareButton(
        'link you want to share',
        document.getElementById('twr'), {
            url: 'link that you want to share',
            count: '1',
            size: 'large'
        }).then(function (el) {
        console.log('button created');
    });
    twttr.events.bind('tweet', function (event) {
        console.log('tweet', event);
    });
});
```

**note** : Maybe `window.twttr` not working in angular so you can use `window['twttr']` instead of `window.twttr` variable.

Answer (score 1):

This will be a helpful [article](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/connect-to-the-twitter-api-in-an-angular-6-app--cms-32315)

```
const express = require('express');
const Twitter = require('twit');

const app = express();
const client = new Twitter({
  consumer_key: 'Consumer Key Here',
  consumer_secret: 'Consumer  Secret  Here',
  access_token: 'Access Token Here',
  access_token_secret: 'Token  Secret Here'
});


app.use(require('cors')());
app.use(require('body-parser').json());

app.post('/post_tweet', (req, res) => {

  tweet = {status:"Hello world"};

    client
      .post(`statuses/update`, tweet)
      .then(timeline => {
        console.log(timeline);

        res.send(timeline);
      })

     .catch(error => {
      res.send(error);
    });


});

app.listen(3000, () => console.log('Server running'));
```

Angular Twitter Service

```
export class TwitterService {

 api_url = 'http://localhost:3000';

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getTimeline() {
    return this.http
      .get<any[]>(this.api_url+'/home_timeline')
      .pipe(map(data => data));

  }

  getMentions() {
    return this.http
      .get<any[]>(this.api_url+'/mentions_timeline')
      .pipe(map(data => data));

  }

}
```